# Substitution for a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Show that 
$$
4\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} \, dy \, dx = \frac{8}{3} \int_0^{\pi /4} (1+ \sec^2 \theta )^{1.5} \, d\theta - \frac{2\pi}{3}
$$

I have tried letting $1+x^2 = \lambda^2$ , $y=\lambda \tan \theta$ , $\frac{dy}{d\theta} = \lambda \sec^2 \theta$. After which

$$\begin{aligned}
4\int_0^1 \int_{\arctan (0/ \lambda)}^{\arctan (1/ \lambda)} \lambda^2 \sec^3 \theta \, d\theta \, dx &= 4\int_0^1 \lambda^2 \left[ 0.5 \sec \theta \tan \theta + 0.5 \ln (\sec \theta + \tan \theta) \right]_{\arctan (0/ \lambda)}^{\arctan (1/ \lambda)}\, dx 
\end{aligned} $$

And then I was convinced this was not the way to go.

Comment: I think you should switch to polar coordinates and then integrate w.r.t. $r=\sqrt {1+x^{2}}$ first. Consider integral over the four quadrants separately.

Comment: Describing $[0, 1]^2$ in polar coordinates doesn't seems like fun though - have you tried computing the integral over $y$ explicitly?

Comment: I am clueless. I did my part for the research and found this: http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-square-to-circle.html , but I am still clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function and the region are symmetric about the line $y=x$, so you can re-write your integral as

$$8\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x,y) \; dy \; dx.$$

So you're integrating over the triangle with vertices $(0,0),$ $(1,0),$ and $(1,1).$

The vertical line $x=1$ has polar equation $r\cos \theta =1$ or $r=\sec \theta.$  So in polar, the integral is

$$8\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\sec \theta} \sqrt{1+r^2}\; r \; dr \; d\theta.$$

Then things are straightforward.